# Unable to connect to move_group action server 'pickup' within allotted time

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Users,
I am trying to use moveIt! but, when launching RViz, this is the error that I get:

Unable to connect to move_group action server 'pickup' within allotted time (30s)

Actually, "pickup" is not in my list, as stated when move_group is launched:

Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...

---

- MoveGroup using:
- ```
  - CartesianPathService
  ```
- ```
  - ExecutePathService
  ```
- ```
  - KinematicsService
  ```
- ```
  - MoveAction
  ```
- ```
  - MotionPlanService
  ```
- ```
  - QueryPlannersService
  ```
- ```
  - StateValidationService
  ```
- ```
  - GetPlanningSceneService
  ```
- ```
  - ApplyPlanningSceneService
  ```
- ```
  - ClearOctomapService
  ```

---

[ INFO] [1485960704.893790868]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1485960704.893821482]: MoveGroup context initialization complete

Thank you for your support!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253506/unable-to-connect-to-move_group-action-server-%27pickup%27-within-allotted-time/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2017-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on 2017-02-01**:
rosparam get /move_group/capabilities give me this result:

move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService               move_group/MoveGroupExecuteService               move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService               move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction               move_group/MoveGroupPlanService

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on 2017-02-01**:
I tried also:
rosparam get / | grep Pick
rosparam get / | grep ick

and results are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pick capability is provided by moveit_ros/manipulation and is called `move_group/MoveGroupPickPlaceAction`.
The MoveGroupInterface used by RViz tries to connect to this capability too, in case you want to use the `pick` functions.

If you intentionally did not load the capability, then you should simply ignore the warning.
It is not a problem as long as you don't try to use the pick functions.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on 2017-02-01**:
Actually, it becomes a problem since RViz seems stuck waiting for this function, and no planning is allowed

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-02-01**:
Ah, right, this is a big problem indeed.
We do not handle this in the code at the moment, so the only way to fix this on your end it so add the PickPlaceAction capability.

Feel free to file an issue in the project repository or propose a patch. The situation there could definitely be improved...

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on 2017-02-02**:
I am sorry that this is becoming a sort of "chat", but the reason for remove PickPlaceAction is related to the error:

Exception while loading move_group capability 'move_group/MoveGroupPickPlaceAction': Failed to load library /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libmoveit_move_group_pick_place_capability.so

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-02-02**:
The exception is a different problem/bug again. Please decide on resolving at least one of them and feel free to open an issue at the project repository for that and/or join the IRC channel to discuss this there.
At least either way forward leaves the scope of answers.ros.org in my opinion.

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on 2017-02-02**:
A "simple" sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit* solved it.
Thank you for the support